# Pre-selected dependable lists in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel coding gurus, i'd like someone to land me a hand in a following problem:

**What I have**:
I have an Excel 2019. Not the 365 edition.
And I have an Excel table with 2 columns. Column **I** contains list of people. And each person in the **I** column has the country of his/her origin denoted in the correspondent cell of **H** column.

For a better view check this picture, plz.

[image]

And I have two *drop-down enabled* cells (**K4** and **L4**). 
**K4** holds the list of all countries, presented in **H** col. 
And **L4** is supposed to have a list of people, avaliable in the col **I**

**Now, the question is:**
How can I code those **K4** and **L4** cells, so that when in K4 cell I select a country, then in the drop down list of L4 cell I'd get the list of only those people from the **I** column that have their country of origin equal to the one in K4?

I feel like it is possible to be done with those array-returning functions but I just can't wrap my head around it all.

Comment: You will need helper columns that are dynamic in what they return.  You cannot go directly from the two column list to a dynamic dependent list.  This does not matter the version of Excel.

Comment: You are trying to tackle a problem that is profoundly easy in Excel O365 (literally two short formulas) and is much more difficult in non-O365 versions.

Comment: @Prema, thank you, I've seen this one and ... this particular one is not much of a help as I do not have (and majority of ppl around me as well) office 365 with all those fancy dynamic arraying functions (as Max R correctly pointed out).

Comment: @MaxR, you are correct. But alas - neither me nor majority of ppl around me do not have O365. So I have to find an old school kind of a solution without VBA scripting as presence of macroses will freak away some of the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working like this so far.

[image]

The functions necessary for this are `INDEX`, `MATCH`, `IF`, `IFERROR`, and `COUNTIF`, which are all available in Excel 2019.

The only thing I'm struggling with (without 365) is that I can't figure out how to remove the white space for the dynamic range.

The formula in column 'E' is to make a unique list of the 'Country' column:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($H$2:$H$20,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:$E1,$H$2:$H$20),0)),"")
```

This formula must begin at least in row 2, as it needs an empty space above it.

Column F is a similarly unique list of column I, but is dynamic based on the value in `K4`: ***Now updated, see edit below**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($I$2:$I$20,MATCH(0,IF($K$4=$H$2:$H$20,COUNTIF($F$1:$F1,$I$2:$I$20),""),0)),"")
```

The validation in `K4` is based on column E, and the validation in `L4` is based on column F.

As I said, without O365 I can't figure out how to remove the white space, but this should at least work for you.

EDIT: I have had another look at this and figured out the whitespace issue:

Data validation for `L4`:

```
=INDIRECT("F2:"&"F"&(COUNTA(F:F)-COUNTIF(F:F," ")+1))
```

As a bonus, the data validation for `K4` can be similar, in case you want to expand column `H` to include more entries:

```
=INDIRECT("E2:"&"E"&(COUNTA(E:E)-COUNTIF(E:E," ")+1))
```

This creates a list from `F2` (which will always be our first value) and will expand dynamically as far down as column `F` has data, given that we change the formula in `F2` to be:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($I$2:$I$20,MATCH(0,IF($K$4=$H$2:$H$20,COUNTIF($F$1:$F1,$I$2:$I$20),""),0))," ")
```

Note that the character in the `IFERROR` of this formula and the `COUNTIF` of the previous is not a space, it's the character from `Alt+255`.

As a final nicety, adding some conditional formatting to cell `L4` will make it so that selecting data in `L4`, and then changing the value of `K4` (so that `L4` is no longer valid) will return whitespace - which is really white text on a white background.

Conditional format formula for `L4`:

```
=NOT(IFERROR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($L$4,TEXTJOIN(" ",1,F:F))),FALSE))
```

Comment: No problem. I think if this is what you were looking for you can mark it as the chosen answer?

Answer (score 0):

The following is my elaboration on @RGilchrist's answer that he presented above. His was the main idea thus all the credit goes to him too.

The functions, needed for this are `INDEX`, `MATCH`, `IF`, `IFERROR`, and `COUNTIF`, which are all available in Excel 2019.

[image]

The formula in column 'E' is to make a unique list of the 'Country' column:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($H$2:$H$17;MATCH(0;COUNTIF($E$1:$E1;$H$2:$H$17);0));"")` 
For example, on the pic you can see a formula of the cell `E2`.
Some comments on this formula:

- it should be entered into the cell by `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` as it is an array formula. And you can see that it is wrapped into curly brackets `{}`.
- the formula needs to have at least 1 cell above it. In this case it is `E1`.
- As you see on the picture - I've deliberately made my dataset sparce, not dence (it has empty rows). To work around having zero in the resultset one has to place `0` to the `E1` cell.
- on the picture my dataset is colored. That hints the fact that I've announced the dataset as a table. This would allow for some neat features like auto extending of the table should I add more rows to it. And that provides for some functionally neat addressing of the column in the dataset. In my locale the table-addressed following formula would be this:
  `=IFERROR(INDEX(Tab_1[Стовпець1];MATCH(0;COUNTIF($E$1:$E2;Tab_1[Стовпець1]);0));"")` where `Tab_1` is the name of the table I've announced. And `[Стовпець1]` is a name of the column in the table.

Column F is a similarly unique list of column I, but is dynamic based on the value in `K4`: `=IFERROR(INDEX($I$2:$I$20,MATCH(0,IF($K$4=$H$2:$H$20,COUNTIF($F$1:$F1,$I$2:$I$20),""),0)),"")`

All comments to previous formula are applicable to this one as well.

The data validation in `K4` is based on column E, and the validation in `L4` is based on column F. But in order to overcome empty space problem in resulting dropdown list the data validation should be based on a formula that uses OFFSET function.
So the data validation source for `K4` would be
`=OFFSET($E$2;;;COUNTIF($E$2:$E$10;"?*"))`
[image]

The relevant screenshot is in my locale but the general interface should be familiar.